# Conversion Error - Leads without the company field populated cannot be converted to a Business Account

Tags: record-type, lead-conversion, error-messages, person-accounts

I have **Person Account** enabled in my org.
[image]

The default Account Record Type for my profile is set to Person Account.
[image]

Whenever I try to Convert leads, I'm getting this error message...

> **Leads without the company field populated cannot be converted to a
>   Business Account**
>
> The company field on the lead detail page must be populated before you
>   can convert the lead to a Business Account. If necessary, add the
>   company field to the lead page layout.

I can't figure out why during conversion SF is attempting to create Business Accounts.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Account record type is picked based on the lead owner's default record type and not based on the user converting the lead.

here's the salesforce [reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004455&language=en_US&type=1)

*When a Lead is converted to an Account, the Lead Record Type does not map over to the Account Record Type. The account record created through Lead Conversion **will not be based on the record type of the user who converted the lead, instead it uses the default record type assigned to the profile of the specified record owner** during Lead conversion.*

Comment: Thank you Vamshi. I cross-checked and the Lead Owner's profile also has Person Account set at the default record type.

Comment: Any further ideas?

Comment: did you check if the lead owner has any default record types in their user settings which might override the profile level defaults ?

Comment: Yes - I did. Contains Person Account as well.